# problem in returning array address from function in C

Tags: c, pointers, scope, c-strings, function-definition

**There comes an error "conflicting types" so what can I do, and prefer a good alternative for this. The main problem is in returning an array from function**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int* freqofchar(char);
int main()
{

    char str[100];
    printf("Enter a sentence below :\n");
    gets(str);
    int* p = freqofchar(str);
    for(int i=0;i<128;i++){
        if(*p>0){
            printf("%c occurred %d times\n",(char) i , *p++);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
int* freqofchar(char str[]){
    int freq[128] = {0};
    for(int i = 0;str[i] != '\0';i++){
        freq[ str[i] ]++;
    }
    return freq;
}
```

Comment: You can't return a statically-allocated array, because it is deallocated once the function returns (and more generally, deallocated outside the scope of its declaration). Instead, allocate this array outside the function, and pass it to then function (which will fill it with data).

Comment: So rewrite the function

Comment: Is that an order???

Comment: Next time, compile your code with all warnings and debug info. With [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) try compiling with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. Consider also using the [Clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) and/or [Frama-C](http://frama-c.com/). Read about [C dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation) and [flexible array members](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member). See also [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c)

Comment: BTW, **`gets`  is obsolete and always dangerous to use**. Read about [undefined behavior in C](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html) and about [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow)

Comment: What's the "standard" duplicate of this question?

Comment: @Jabberwocky: there are too many of them....

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch i Know, but there must be one or two good ones, like the famous "Why are these constructs i++ + ++i undefined behaviour".

Comment: @goodvibration: The array is not static in the sense used by the C standard in regard to storage duration, if it were, returning it (by pointer) would be fine. The size of the array is static in the English sense of being fixed, but that is irrelevant to whether returning it is okay; making the array variable length instead of static length would not make it okay to return.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: That's why I wrote "statically-allocated" and not `static` (with the notation which emphasizes the "static" keyword).

Comment: @goodvibration: The array is not statically allocated in either the C sense or the common English sense.

Comment: @goodvibration: If you want to define “statically allocated” as meaning allocated in some manner fixed at compile time, such as decrementing a fixed amount from the stack pointer, rather than allocated with a run-time method such as using `malloc` to obtain memory from a run-time managed region, then the comment is still wrong, because that definition of “statically allocated” includes objects of static storage duration, which are safe to return. The statement in the comment is false.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 problems:

1) conflicting types:

```
int* freqofchar(char)
```

in declaration, but

```
int* freqofchar(char str[])
```

in definition.

2) You are returning freq allocated on stack from freqofchar

Comment: A good answer would not just point out the problem but also how to fix each of the issues.

Comment: The proper concept to use is that the lifetime of the array ends when the function returns, not that it is allocated on a stack.

Answer (score 1):

The error you see is due to mismatch in the function *prototype* and its actual *definition*.

However, you have other problems, too:

- `gets` function has been removed from the C standard (since) for a good reason and should never be used in any case. You can use `fgets` instead to read input. But you need to remove the newline if `fgets` reads it in.
- You are returning a pointer to a local variable, whose lifetime isn't valid once the function `freqofchar` returns, which is undefined behaviour. You can instead pass another argument. Generally you may want to consider dynamic allocation (e.g. via `malloc`) but in this case - you only need a small array - an array local to the main function, which has [automatic storage duration](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.4) and thus its lifetime is valid for the duration of `main()` and it can be safely passed to `freqofchar` function without it being invalid or de-allocated as the object's (`freq` being the object in reference here) lifetime is still valid in when it's being used in `freqofchar()` - is better-suited here.

Here's how a fixed solution would looks like:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void freqofchar(char*, int*);

int main()
{
    char str[100] = {0};
    int freq[256] = {0};

    printf("Enter a sentence below :\n");
    fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin);

    /* Remove the newline if present. */
    char *p = strchr(str, '\n');
    if (p) *p = '\0';

    freqofchar(str, freq);

    for(size_t i = 0;i < sizeof freq; i++) {
        if(freq[i]) {
            printf("%c occurred %d times\n", i, freq[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void freqofchar(char str[], int freq[])
{
    for(int i = 0;str[i] != '\0';i++) {
        freq[ str[i] ]++;
    }
}
```

Comment: `str` could contain chars > 128..., so `int freq[256]` would be more appropriate.

Comment: @snr-ReinstateMonica it's not about the length but about the possibility that the user enters chars with an ascii value larger than 12, for example `à` (this happens frequently on non english systems".

Comment: I meat "larger than **128**" in my previous comment

Comment: IMO this answer does not show how to return a "fresh" object from the function. IMO it is a bit OT

Comment: @snr-ReinstateMonica who told you that

Comment: @P__J__ The question isn't about returning a "fresh" objects.

Comment: @Jabberwocky There could be unprintable chars even under 128 and that input can also contain chars greater than 256 (multibyte chars). For what little value it might have, I have changed it to 256 now.

Comment: Whether the variable is local is not the correct concept to use. An array defined inside the function with `static` would be local yet would be okay to return. The proper concept is that the array is managed automatically by the C implementation (has *automatic storage duration*), and its lifetime ends when the function returns.

Answer (score -1):

The function parameter is declared in the function declaration as having the type `char`

```
int* freqofchar(char);
                ^^^^^
```

But in the function declaration that at the same is its definition

```
int* freqofchar(char str[]){
                ^^^^^^^^^
```

the parameter is declared as having the type `char []` (that is adjusted by the compiler to the type `char *`).

This typo is the reason of the compiler message.

But in any case the function shall be declared at least like

```
unsigned int * freqofchar( const char [] );
```

That is there is no sense to define frequencies as having signed integer type and the parameter shall have the qualifier `const` because the passed string is not being changed in the function.

The program has undefined behavior because the function returns pointer to a local array with the automatic storage duration that will not be alive after exiting the function.

```
int* freqofchar(char str[]){
    int freq[128] = {0};
    //...
    return freq;
}
```

You should either allocate the array dynamically or declare it with the storage specifier `static`. In the last case you need to reset elements of the array to zeroes each time when the function is called.

The function `gets` is an unsafe function and is not supported by the C standard any more. Instead use the standard C function `fgets`.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned int* freqofchar( const char *);

int main( void )
{
    enum { N = 100 };
    char str[N];
    str[0] = '\0';

    printf( "Enter a sentence below : " );

    fgets( str, N, stdin );

    // remove the appended new line character '\n'
    str[ strcspn( str, "\n" ) ] = '\0';

    unsigned int *p = freqofchar( str );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < 128; i++ )
    {
        if ( p[i] )
        {
            printf( "'%c' occurred %u times\n", ( char )i , p[i] );
        }
    }

    free( p );

    return 0;
}

unsigned int * freqofchar( const char str[] )
{
    enum { N = 128 };

    unsigned int *freq = calloc( N, sizeof( unsigned int ) );

    while ( *str ) ++freq[ ( size_t )*str++ ];

    return freq;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Enter a sentence below : Hello World!
' ' occurred 1 times
'!' occurred 1 times
'H' occurred 1 times
'W' occurred 1 times
'd' occurred 1 times
'e' occurred 1 times
'l' occurred 3 times
'o' occurred 2 times
'r' occurred 1 times
```

If to define the function with the static storage specifier then its definition can look the following way.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

unsigned int* freqofchar( const char *);

int main( void )
{
    enum { N = 100 };
    char str[N];
    str[0] = '\0';

    printf( "Enter a sentence below : " );

    fgets( str, N, stdin );

    // remove the appended new line character '\n'
    str[ strcspn( str, "\n" ) ] = '\0';

    unsigned int *p = freqofchar( str );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < 128; i++ )
    {
        if ( p[i] )
        {
            printf( "'%c' occurred %u times\n", ( char )i , p[i] );
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

unsigned int * freqofchar( const char str[] )
{
    enum { N = 128 };

    static unsigned int freq[N];

    memset( freq, 0, N * sizeof( unsigned int ) );

    while ( *str ) ++freq[ ( size_t )*str++ ];

    return freq;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

1. You make one of the most common mistakes in the C programming. You return the pointer to the object which does not exist after the function return.

possible solutions

a. use dynamicaly allocated memory

```
int* freqofchar(char *str)
{
    int *freq = malloc(128 * sizeof(*freq)); // or if you want to zero it calloc

    /* ... */    
    return freq;
}
```

but you need to free the allocated memory when not needed.

b. use static array or global array

```
int* freqofchar(char *str)
{
    static freq[128];

    /* ... */    
    return freq;
}
```

or

```
static freq[128];

int* freqofchar(char *str)
{

    /* ... */    
    return freq;
}
```

Downsides of this solution: the function is not reentrant, the freq array cannot be passed to the async task and functions as it can be changed if function is called again.
The initialisation happens only one time before first call to the function.

c. Wrap it in the union or struct and return the whole object

```
struct freqstruct {
    int freq[128];
};

struct freqstruct freqofchar(char *str)
{
    struct freqstruct freq = {0};

    /* ... */    
    return freq;
}
```

Downside - the whole array wrapped into the `struct` is copied. It is not very memory and performance wise.

2. Your definition does not match the declaration of the function. It shows that you did not put enough effort.

```
int* freqofchar(char *str)

int* freqofchar(char *str)
{
     /* ... */
}
```

or - but I personally do not like this notation as it makes beginners think that the array is passed not the pointer.

```
int* freqofchar(char str[])

int* freqofchar(char str[])
{
     /* ... */
}
```

3. This functions is not const corrent - the parameter `str` should be `const char *str` or `const char str[]`